# Undefined function in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, undefined-function

I am writing a lisp function and I keep getting EVAL - undefined function x when I try to return the value of x from the function.

```
(defun p+ (x y)
    (recurcollect (gluelist x y) '()))

(defun isinlist (x y)
    (if (car y)
        (if (equal (cdr x) (cdar y))
            t
            (if (cdr y)
                (isinlist(x (cdr y))) 
                NIL))
        NIL))

(defun collectvalue (x y) ;takes an expression and a list and returns the sum of all like expressions from the list
    (if (equal x NIL)
        (print '(x is NIL))
        (if (equal (cdr x) (cdar y)) 
             (if (cdr y)
                (collectvalue (list (+ (car x) (caar y)) (cdr x)) (cdr y))
                (list (+ (car x) (caar y)) (cdr x)))
        (if (cdr y)
            (collectvalue x (cdr y))
            x))))

(defun recurcollect (x y) ;returns a flat list of collected expressions
    (if (isinlist (car x) y)
        (recurcollect (cdr x) y)
        (if (cdr x)
            (recurcollect x (cons y (collectvalue (car x) (cdr x))))
            (cons y (car x)))))

(defun gluelist (x y)
    (if (cdr x)
        (cons (car x) (gluelist (cdr x) y))
        (cons (car x) y)))

(print (p+ '(2 0 1) '(4 0 1)))  ;(6 0 1)
```

I believe the error is caused by the x at the end of the function but I cant see why, as far as I can tell my brackets are correctly paired up and I cant see why it is trying to evaluate x as a function.

Comment: Are you getting this problem when you try to define the function, or when you try to run it? What exactly are you evaluating at the REPL?

Comment: @L33tminion It happens when I run it. What I'm evaluating is polynomials, each value is represented as (coefficient, power of first variable, power of 2nd variable, etc.) so 3x^2 would be (3 2) 3xy^2 would be (3 1 2) so on. x is a single term and y is a list of terms representing a polynomial. The purpose of this function is to collect all the like terms.

Comment: please format your code properly (emacs will do that for you) and copy and paste your complete interaction, i.e., how you are calling your function and what Lisp prints.

Comment: @sds I dont have access to emacs as I'm using a public computer, could you tell me which areas of my formatting need fixing?

Comment: What exactly are you running at the REPL? Can you copy and paste the exact thing?

Comment: @L33tminion I've edited my post to contain the full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `isinlist` which is called recursively as `(isinlist(x (cdr y)))`.
`(x ...)` is interpreted as a function call of function `x`.
You probably want `(isinlist x (cdr y))` instead.

Incidentally, you can replace `isinlist` with [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) (with `:key #'cdr :test #'equal`).

Comment: I think you may be right, but member wont work due to the nature of the input, it needs to test the equality of the cdr only.

Comment: I added proposed `member` keyword args